# How to know how much energy storage has powerbank?

Tags: voltage, watts, ups, powerbanks

I just looked to [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-we-dont-have-20-000-mAh-or-40-000-mAh-battery-in-laptop-whereas-we-are-getting-up-to-5-000-mAh-battery-in-a-small-mobile-Compared-to-the-size-of-mobiles-cant-we-have-a-high-capacity-battery-for-laptops) question and I don't understand how to know how much Wh [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32813376074.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.72ec2b70OaZOB2&algo_pvid=81a5c81d-5021-49de-81d9-ea78eb62a449&algo_expid=81a5c81d-5021-49de-81d9-ea78eb62a449-9&btsid=eb57c54a-92c0-4075-8d10-966162bb835a&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3,searchweb201603_55) powerbank has (click "Specifications" tab), because it has different output voltages and I don't know how to calculate if it's 18Ah * 12V = 216Wh or 18Ah * 19V = 342Wh?

Comment: You need the battery voltage to calculate the watt hours from the ampere hours.  The output voltage doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information provided on the vendor web site is not very clear or specific. If you really care about this you should look for a different vendor, one that provides complete specifications.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the power bank a good way to evaluate is to first fully charge the unit. Then put on a constant current discharge load. Monitor the discharge voltage duration with a low cost USB voltage data logger to determine how long of time it takes till the unit cuts out.

From this you can directly determine the power bank energy density at the chosen load rate.

This procedure is valuable to learn the real capabilities on the power bank. You cannot trust the numbers given by manufacturers because they are often fake inflated data in marketing claims.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon how many cells are in the unit. There is probably only one with ~3.7V output so the energy is probably 18Ah * 3.7 = ~66Wh.

Comment: How do you guess if it's ~3.7V?

Comment: Does every cell has everywhere has 3.7V?

Comment: @vasik988 - If it is Li-Ion it will be 3.7v +/- 0.5V.  The exact construction would determine if it has a fully charged voltage of 4.2V, 3.7V or even 3.3V. The voltage will also change during discharge from the peak down to ~3V when discharged. It's a guess since there is no other information.

Answer (score 0):

There's waht they're claiming and there's what it *is*.

This pack is advertised as having output ranges from 12 to 19 volts. Remember that ratio.

One clue is in the graphic:  "18000/28800mAh polymer 3-port" *That ratio seems familiar...*

```
 18000 mAh x 19V = 342,000 mWh
 28800 mAh x 12V = 345,600 mWh
```

**Those numbers are very close, aren't they?**

These numbers jibe; they seem to be claiming 340 watt-hours *at 100% efficiency*, **which they loudly disclaim that you won't get**.

By contrast, Anker wants $60 for a 100 watt-hour Anker Power Core II 20000, so 60 cents per watt-hour.  The very large Goal Zero Yeti 3000 watt-hour, is $2300, or 80 cents per watt-hour.

So if you figure 80 cents per Wh, I would expect $80 to buy a 100-125 watt-hour unit from a reputable maker.

*So golly, that unit off AliExpress is a great deal, eh?*

*snicker*

I suspect a teardown of this unit will reveal batteries incapable of storing 340 WH... and probably more like 100 WH *if that*...  there's no free lunch...